# Delphi constructors paramenters by reference

Tags: delphi

I have a class that looks like this:

```
type
 TLogin = class(TThread)
  private
   //variables...
  protected
   procedure Execute; override;
  public
   constructor Create(testo: TLabel; splash: TRectangle; username: string; labels: LabelArray);
 end;
```

I know that a constructor can take an endless number or parameters but I always prefer to have a little amount and I guess that 4 is the max. I have managed to reduce the numbers of parameters using a `LabelArray`.

```
type
 LabelArray = array of TLabel;
```

It has a length of 15-22 (decided at runtime) and I was wondering if this code is correct or not (look at the `var`):

```
constructor Create(testo: TLabel; splash: TRectangle; username: string; var labels: LabelArray);
```

Does this makes sense? Of course the code compiles but I am not sure if the array is already passed by reference. I don't want to make a copy because that would be useless; I am going to change the text of those labels inside my array so I'd prefer a pass-by-reference.

This is a class that runs in a thread separated from the GUI so I'm calling a `Queue` at a certain point to update the labels' text of the main form. It would be

```
Queue(nil, procedure
           begin
            FLabelArray[0].Text := '...';
            FLabelArray[1].Text := '...'; //and so on
           end);
```

For this reason I think that a copy wouldn't be useful.

Comment: Should be const instead of var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic arrays are reference counted, so it doesn't really matter in this situation if you pass it by value or by reference. And even if you were passing around copies, the array holds object pointers, which are lightweight to make copies of. Your `Queue()` calls would still be operating on the original `TLabel` objects.

Comment: @RaffaeleRossi: For a dynamic array, yes.  All the `var` does is avoids one pair of increment/decrement of the reference count. Using `const` instead of `var` would do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Delphi dynamic arrays are reference types. Passing the array with `var` doesn't accomplish anything because your constructor isn't actually assigning a new value to the `labels` parameter. There's no method of passing a dynamic array that would cause a *copy* to be created.

It's sufficient for your constructor to assign the `labels` parameter to the `FLabelArray` field with a simple assignment statement:

```
FLabelArray := labels;
```

That increases the array's *reference count*, so it will remain a valid array for the lifetime of the thread object you've just constructed.

Comment: In case of a non-dynamic array (such as array[0..2] of TLabels) the var would have been useless too?

Comment: No, @Alberto. It would prevent a copy of the array from being created in the constructor's prologue, and it would allow changes made to the array to be visible in the caller. Not usually what you want. Prefer to pass things `const`. That prevents the copy, and it also prevents modifications.